# Combining 2 ORACLE Queries into 1 query

Tags: php, sql, oracle

So i have 2 queries which one of them is a subquery using the values from the first query. I need to make this into 1 query so that i can put them as a view. So the first query is ,

```
    SELECT LEVEL WEEK_NUM_INCR,
           TO_CHAR (start_date + (LEVEL - 1) * 7, 'DD-MON-YYYY') START_WEEK_DATE,
           TO_CHAR (start_date + (LEVEL) * 7, 'DD-MON-YYYY') END_WEEK_DATE 
      FROM (SELECT PS.PROJECT_START_DT start_date,
                   PS.JOB_NAME JOB_NAME,
                   PS.PROJECT_END_DT end_date
              FROM PROJECT_SPAN PS
             WHERE PS.JOB_NAME = :JOBNAME) RS
CONNECT BY start_date + (LEVEL - 1) * 7 < end_date;
```

and the second query is,

```
  SELECT SUM (DO.ONSITE_UPD_QTY) ONSITESUM,
         SUM (DO.ONSITE_UPD_QTY * MD.WEIGHT) TOTALONSITEWEIGHT,
    FROM PROJECT P
         LEFT OUTER JOIN DTL_ERC_UPD@WELTES_SITEMON_LINK DO
            ON DO.PROJECT_NAME = P.PROJECT_NAME
         LEFT OUTER JOIN MASTER_DRAWING MD ON MD.HEAD_MARK = DO.HEAD_MARK
   WHERE     DO.UPD_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE (:STARTDATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
                             AND TO_DATE (:ENDDATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
         AND P.PROJECT_NO = :PROJNO
GROUP BY P.PROJECT_NO;
```

the second query use the values :STARTDATE and :ENDDATE from the first query START_WEEK_DATE and END_WEEK_DATE as the ranged value from specific date range in the first query.

so the whole method in php can be seen in http://pastie.org/9938791
but its impossible for to put them together and assign the value inside the JSON. Please help me on combining those 2 queries.. I really appreciate it

Comment: Can't you just make a view of the first query? Or use the WITH construction?

Comment: I tried the view but the problem is in the JOBNAME...

Comment: the week range keep running in recursive loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the first query as a subquery using the WITH-Clause:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm

```
WITH JOBNAME AS (1stQuery)
SELECT-CLAUSE USING JOBNAME as Inlineview (in the FROM-Condition).
```

e.g. http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause.php